# React Native VR - Viro alternatives

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, virtual-reality

I have been using React Viro for 2 years. It was working pretty stable for both Android and iOS. Lastly, Viro dropped official support, moved the repo to the community and from this time it started to be a nightmare. Deprecated APIs, store rejections etc. My hands are tightened as I'm a JavaScript developer thus I can't patch it without spending months on learning new Google Cardboard API and Objective-C stuff.

One of my clients uses VR only so I don't care about AR for now. Do we have any other alternatives (paid one are acceptable)? I'm looking for something stable, up-to-date which will work for the next 2 years. Is there any native port to React Native?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a similar situation, using Viro just for VR and strugling with the issue that Viro is not working on iOS 14.x due to deprecation of Google VR (replaced by Google with Google Cardboard). After several days of research I decided to patch only the iOS 14.x issue since all other OS and versions are working fine with Viro.
My choice is [egjs-view360](https://naver.github.io/egjs-view360), a web based solution that looks robust. I know is not native (nor React-Native) but after a try I have a working and reliable version.

Sadly, includes:

- egjs.view360.
- some extra libs from egjs like (PanoController).
- web-vr-polyfill to make VR work with Safari.
- react-native-web-view to load the player into my app.
- and handle motion and orientation permission required by Safari.

Not the ideal solution, however considering the uncertainty moment of VR (old web VR api deprecated, new web XR in draft; Google VR deprecated, Google Cardboard still hard to use with RN), this is an understandable and controllable stack for me.

If anyone in similar situation have another option, I'm eager to know about it.

Comment: Looks like Viro is now working with iOS 14.4 and even with 14.5! VR is actually dead but you can still use ViroARScene when you need a 360 Image/Video viewer.